# FreePBX Calls connect but no voice

Tags: virtualbox, voip, asterisk, pbx, freepbx

I have FreePBX running on virtualbox on a windows 8 host the network adapter is set to bridged and I have assigned it a static IP address. My windows 8 host is connected to a typical home wireless router. I'm using X-Lite on the windows 8 machine to make calls to a MetroPCS cellphone. The phone will ring however I can't hear audio in either direction.

When googling this most of what I find has to do with NAT not being configured properly. I have tried forwarding ports 5060 UDP and 10001-20000 UDP to the freePBX virtual box with no success. I also tried using the DMZ option that my router provides to put that virtual box on the DMZ. In both cases I could connect but still no audio in either direction. I'm assuming this DMZ setting opens all ports to that machine but I can't be sure and I didn't leave it there for long so it's possible my router didn't have time to respond to the changes. I also found issues with incompatible codecs somewhere in the pipeline so I made sure FreePBX and X-lite were setup to support ULAW, ALAW and GSM.

I strongly suspect it's some kind of networking issue am I missing a port in my forwarding?

P.S. At this point my goal right now is to call my phone and hear audio go both ways I'm concerned with taking calls yet that will come later. I don't see why I would need to punch holes in my firewall to make an outgoing call .

Comment: I think issues here is virtualization/windows firewall settings. Note, asterisk in virtualization require expert knowledge in both tech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the audio settings in X-Lite I had the incorrect options selected in SoftPhone>Preferences>Devices The audio device was not set to the proper output so I didn't hear anything on my headset and the microphone was not set to the proper input device so I didn't hear anything on the cellphone. For the outgoing calls only I didn't need to open any ports.